# Mapping categories in Python

Tags: python

I have a large dataset and one of the columns is a list of company types. I noticed a lot of them have similar type of descriptions of type. For example, "Surgical appliances" and "Surgical Instruments" can be simplified to "Surgical." Then "eyewear", "ophthalmic" "optometry" can be simplified to "eyewear." How do I write the code in Python, so that it goes through each item in the column and simplifies it to one group? Something along the lines of:

```
for i= 1:n
    if df['Company Type'][i] contains 'Surgical'
       then df['Company Type'] == 'Surgical'
    else if df[Company Type][i] contains optometry, opthalamy
        then df['Company Type'] == 'Eyewear'
```

I apologize if this question is a little vague. I really don't know how to get started on this
Thank you

Comment: Are you using Pandas?

Comment: In general the `in` operator checks for containment in Python , but that probably won't help you much here.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use pandas. Load your dataframe to pandas, say the name of the dataframe is df.

Then all you have to do is,

```
df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].map(d)
```

Where d is the dictionary. In your case it's a bit more complicated since you are using 'contains'. In that case I would make a function like this

```
def map_company(row):
    company = row['Company Name']
    if company in 'Surgical':
         return 'Surgical'
    #include more elif statements here

df['Company Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: map_company(x),axis=1)
```

An even better way to do this is to use .str.extract method of pandas shown [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

Write a regex for all your Company Names and this function will return a new column with the matched substring.

Comment: you wouldn't even need the lambda, since it has the same call signature as `map_company`. You could just write `df.apply(map_company, axis=1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! So what about when I have to group optomery, sunglasses, opthalmy under just "Eyewear." I would have to know all the categories and list them out in the if condition correct (but that seems like a pain)? How would the if else statement look for that?

Comment: Is this correct?def map_company(row):
    company = row['SIC_Desc']
    if company in 'Surgical':
         return 'Surgical'
    elif company in ['Eye', 'glasses', 'opthal', 'spectacles', 'optometers']:
        return 'Eyewear'
    elif company in ['Cotton', 'Bandages', 'gauze', 'tape']:
        return 'First Aid'
    elif company in ['Dental', 'Denture']:
        return 'Dental'
    elif company in ['Wheelchairs', 'Walkers', 'braces', 'crutches', 'ortho']:
        return 'Mobility equipments'
    else:
        return 'Other'

df['SIC_Desc'] = df.apply(map_company,axis=1)

Comment: Map whatever you can just by using "contains" keyword. The ones that need an array, you can use a dictionary.
    dic_map = {'Eye':'Eyewear','glasses':Eyewear','Cotton'} #fill this dictionary

Now run the first code that I had typed up in the post, (the map one)

Comment: @siddarth iyer can you please provide a sample code of this. not sure if i understand your direction

Comment: There are two types of mapping required. One which is not exact, for example mapping Surgical Appliances to Surgical. Here you make the function, just like you described in the previous comment. For ones which are exact like Denture to Dental and Wheelchairs to Mobility, I would use a dictionary. You know about python dictionaries right? Just make a dictionary mapping keys to values. 

dic_map = {'Eye':'Eyewear','glasses':Eyewear','Cotton'} #fill this dictionary

And then do df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].replace(d)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of the sub-sectors are unique, you can create a dictionary of the sectors to the sub-sectors and then reverse it.  Use the reversed dictionary to map the sub-sectors (`Company Type`) to their appropriate sectors.

```
groups = { 
    "Surgical": ["Surgical appliances", "Surgical Instruments"],
    "Eyewear": ["eyewear", "ophthalmic", "optometry"]
}
reversed_groups = {v: k for k in groups for v in groups[k]}

df = pd.DataFrame({'company': list('ABCDE'), 'Company Type': reversed_groups.keys()})
>>> df
           Company Type company
0             optometry       A
1            ophthalmic       B
2  Surgical Instruments       C
3   Surgical appliances       D
4               eyewear       E

>>> df.assign(sector=df['Company Type'].map(reversed_groups))
           Company Type company    sector
0             optometry       A   Eyewear
1            ophthalmic       B   Eyewear
2  Surgical Instruments       C  Surgical
3   Surgical appliances       D  Surgical
4               eyewear       E   Eyewear
```